# c remove new line char help

Tags: c, newline, fgets

Im fairly new to c sorry if this is a stupid question!

i have this:

```
  fgets(question,200,stdin);
  char *memq = malloc(sizeof(strlen(question)));
  memq= question;
```

however the question variable always has a new line on the end of it !
how do i remove this / prevent it happening?

i have tried this:

```
  fgets(question,200,stdin);
  char *memq = malloc(sizeof(strlen(question))-sizeof(char));
  memq= question;
```

there was no effect!

Comment: The assignment `memq = question` will leak memory because you'll lose your only pointer to the `malloc`-ed memory. I believe you meant to use `strcpy()`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

to get rid of the newline, before your malloc, do :

```
question[strlen(question)-1] = 0;
```

an alternative (suggested in the comments below) would be to do the following instead:

```
question[strcspn(question, "\n")] = '\0';
```

change the malloc line to:

```
char *memq = malloc(strlen(question)+1);
```

change the assignation line:

```
memq = question;
```

to:

```
strcpy (memq, question);
```

Comment: line 1 replaces the newline with a null (0 or '\0') - line 2 allocates memory for the read string plus 1 byte for the null character; line 4 (replaces line 3) copies your read string into the allocated buffer.  Note too that you'll have to free this allocated buffer at some time in the future (it's your job as a C programmer)

Comment: I would replace `question[strlen(question)-1] = 0;` with `question[strcspn(question, "\n")] = '\0';`. If the question is longer than 200 chars, the former will overwrite whatever char is at the penultimate location (it won't be a newline) whereas the latter will *only* NUL out the newline.

Comment: @SiegeX - sure, but we're already in a world of hurt if question is longer than 200 chars -- we all know better than to ask how I know that :)

Comment: @Kevin Although that may be true with this particular case, using `strcspn()` over `strlen()` is painless to write and can *only* help. It also promotes good practice for that time when you were *sure* 20 chars was good enough but wasn't.  As you said "it's your job as a C programmer" (to take care of the details). Using `strcspn()` also has the added benefit that the code is self documenting as to what you are trying to replace.

Comment: @SiegeX - sorry, didn't mean to sound like I was disagreeing when I was not :)  only pointing out what happens in your edge case. (note the upvote and the edit to the answer)

Answer (score 2):

This code is badly broken.

You need to allocate `strlen+1` bytes into `memq` if you plan to copy the data there (why are you doing `sizeof`?  that will allocate 4 bytes since `sizeof(strlen())` is `sizeof(int)`).

You cannot just assign `question` to `memq` and expect the data to be copied in.  All this does is overwrite the pointer you just `malloc`-ed into `memq`, leaking it.  You have to do

```
strcpy(memq, question);
```

That's why you need the extra byte in `memq`, since this includes a null terminator. At this point you are in position to remove the newline from `memq` as noted elsewhere.

Answer (score 1):

Let's say your input is ABCDEn where the n represents the new line.

You're going to be reading in ABCDEn0 where 0 represents null, which terminates the string.

So, by taking off the last char, you're taking off the null, not the newline. I would take off the last char as you are, but then set the (new) last char to null to terminate your string.

Answer (score 1):

In both cases, `memq = question` is **wrong**.  You've just lost your pointer to new newly-allocated space, and instead copied the address of the first character of `question` to `memq`

Use `strcpy` or `memcpy` instead, to copy the *contents* of the string pointed to by `question` to the contents of the memory pointed to by `memq`.

Answer (score 0):

Hint:
Remove the last character! (Hint to hint: you know the length)